# How to remove outer array

Tags: php

This is my data

```
Array 
(
    [t] => Array
        (
            [0] => SS
        )

    [size] => Array
        (
            [0] => 85
        )
)
```

result should be

```
[t] => Array
    (
        [0] => SS
    )

[size] => Array
    (
        [0] => 85
    )
```

Comment: Looks like this is the first index of main array... I mean content.

Comment: If you do a `print_r($your_arr)`, Dont you get the result you need? without making any change?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let original array is `$array` then

```
 $array = $array[0]
```

will give you what you want.

Answer (score 3):

Use the list function to set them to variables.

```
$data = array_values(array(
    't' => array('SS'),
    'size' => array(85)
));

list($t, $size) = $data;
```

**Edit:** Add `array_values` as the old solution produces Undefined index warnings.

```
print_r($t); //array(0 => 'SS')
print_r($size); //array(0 => 85)
```

Answer (score 3):

use [extract](http://php.net/manual/en/function.extract.php) function

```
extract(
    Array(
        't' => Array(0 => SS),
        'size' => Array(0 => 85)
    )
);

print_r($t);    //  Array ( [0] => SS )
print_r($size); //  Array ( [0] => 85 )
```

Comment: here t and size is not static

Answer (score 1):

Just do  :

```
$myVariable[0]
```

if your array is contained in variable called $myVariable

Answer (score 1):

use [current](http://php.net/manual/en/function.current.php):

```
 $array = current($array);
```